# Prove that $q(a_i)\in \{a_1,..., a_n\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be polynomials with rational coefficients such that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $a_1,..., a_n\in \mathbb{C}$ be the complex roots of $p$, and suppose that $q(a_1)=a_2$. Prove that $q(a_i)\in \{a_1,..., a_n\}$ for all $i\in {2, 3,..., n}$.

Comment: Have you covered Euclid's algorithm for computing the gcd of two polynomials? So that you know that the gcd of two polynomials with rational coefficients also has rational coefficients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The given bits imply that $a_1$ is a zero of the polynomial $p(q(x))$. Why does this imply that $\gcd(p(x),p(q(x)))=p(x)$?